# Memcpy Fails with access violation - Vulkan copying to vertex buffer

Tags: c++, memcpy, vulkan

I'm trying to pass some data to the GPU in Vulkan. AFAIK, the only way to do this is using memcpy. This works with a smaller vector, but with a larger model, I get a an access violation exception when I try to do it. The same method working in another implementation on the same machine. What should I be looking for? Thanks

Here's the code

```
void VulkanAllocator::createVertexBuffer(std::vector<HE2_Vertex>* vertices, VkBuffer& vertexBuffer, VkDeviceMemory& vertexBufferMemory)
{
VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(HE2_Vertex) * vertices->size();

VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;

createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

VkMemoryRequirements memReqs;

vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(vdi->device, stagingBuffer, &memReqs);


void* data;

if (vkMapMemory(vdi->device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, (size_t)memReqs.size, 0, &data) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::exception("Bad Memory map!");
}

memcpy(data, vertices->data(), (size_t)memReqs.size); //Crash after this line


vkUnmapMemory(vdi->device, stagingBufferMemory);

createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT,
    VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferMemory);

copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, vertexBuffer, bufferSize);

vkDestroyBuffer(vdi->device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
vkFreeMemory(vdi->device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
}
```

And CreateBuffer looks like this

```
void VulkanAllocator::createBuffer(VkDeviceSize size, VkBufferUsageFlags usage, VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties, VkBuffer& buffer, VkDeviceMemory& bufferMemory)
{
    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo = {};
bufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
bufferInfo.size = size;
bufferInfo.usage = usage;
bufferInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

if (vkCreateBuffer(vdi->device, &bufferInfo, nullptr, &buffer) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create vertex buffer");
}

VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;

vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(vdi->device, buffer, &memRequirements);

VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};

allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
allocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

if (vkAllocateMemory(vdi->device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &bufferMemory) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate vertex buffer memory");
}

vkBindBufferMemory(vdi->device, buffer, bufferMemory, 0);
}
```

The vector is created like so (if you've gone through https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ you're probably recognizing my refactoring). HE2_Model simply contains a vector of `HE2_Vertex` s and a vector of `uint32_t` s. I don't know if relevant but I haven't written a copy constructor for `HE2_Vertex`.

HE2_Model* model = new HE2_Model();

```
//Using tiny_obj_loader to pull in from a file
tinyobj::attrib_t attrib;
std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;

std::string warn, err;

if (!tinyobj::LoadObj(&attrib, &shapes, &materials, &warn, &err, filename.c_str()))
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't load model!");
}

std::unordered_map<HE2_Vertex, uint32_t> uniqueVertices = { };

for (const auto& shape : shapes)
{
    for (const auto& index : shape.mesh.indices)
    {
        HE2_Vertex vertex = {};

        vertex.pos = {
            attrib.vertices[3 * index.vertex_index + 0],
            attrib.vertices[3 * index.vertex_index + 1],
            attrib.vertices[3 * index.vertex_index + 2] };


        vertex.texCoord = {
            attrib.texcoords[2 * index.texcoord_index + 0],
            1.0f - attrib.texcoords[2 * index.texcoord_index + 1] };

        if (uniqueVertices.count(vertex) == 0)
        {
            uniqueVertices[vertex] = static_cast<uint32_t>(model->vertices.size());
            model->vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }

        model->indices.push_back(uniqueVertices[vertex]);
    }
}


HE2_Instance::renderBackend->onAddModel(model);

return model;
```

Comment: `memcpy(data, vertices->data(), (size_t)memReqs.size); //Crash after this line`  --  Did you use a debugger to inspect what those values are?  If so, what are they?  The first thing you should be doing is to establish that `memReqs.size` and `vertices->data()` contain "reasonable" values.

Comment: They do. Memreqs size is slightly larger than the bufferSize. Have checked in my other program that does work too and they're the same values. I'm fairly sure the error isn't in the above code, as I've more or less copied it from the working implementation. I don't really know how to go about debugging it though

Comment: Given the code you posted, there is no way to know if `vertices` is a pointer to a valid vector -- start verifying that the pointer is indeed valid and not invalidated in any way.  There also is no way to know if `VulkanAllocator` is a valid object instance -- if it isn't a valid instance, then no operation would be safe in that function.

Comment: VulkanAllocator is valid, have just checked. Starting to think something is wrong with my vector however - ```std::vector<HE2_Vertex> newVector = *vertices``` also causes an access violation - I'm under the impression this should work?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question with details as to how I'm creating the vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infuriatingly enough, this was fixed with a rebuild. I have multiple projects within the one visual studio solution, and I simply need to learn not to rely on project dependencies, the first thing I always need to do with memory error and exceptions is rebuild every project. Top tip for anyone with weird access violations and behavior etc - Rebuild Rebuild Rebuild!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that's crashing:

`memcpy(data, vertices->data(), (size_t)memReqs.size); //Crash after this line`

You've said in comments that "Memreqs size is slightly larger than the bufferSize" i.e. `memReqs.size` is larger than `bufferSize` which is the full size of the vector (`sizeof(HE2_Vertex) * vertices->size();`), so your memcpy is going to be reading more data from vertices->data() than it's allowed to, this is undefined behaviour which would crash sometimes. You should use this instead:

`memcpy(data, vertices->data(), (size_t)bufferSize);`

(and probably add something like `assert(bufferSize <= memReqs.size);` too)

Comment: It was originally buffer size, and using advice from someone else who uses vulkan I changed it to memreqs.size. Neither work, Using bufferSize makes more sense though so I shall change it back. I have just retested to confirm it doesn't work. I think I'm doing something more fundamentally wrong with my vector in the first place. I can't do ```std::vector<HE2_Vertex> newVector = *vertices``` for example without the same crash